# Is offering a "Restore Purchases" option mandatory when using only StoreKit2 in iOS 15?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit, ios15

This is a fairly simple question, but couldn't find the answer with research.

I know with the original StoreKit API, you had to offer a user the ability to restore purchases. However, with StoreKit2, the WWDC video explains that restoring purchases should rarely, if ever, be required because StoreKit2 automatically listens and keeps transactions up to date.

So, is adding a restore purchase button still mandatory if uses only StoreKit2 and has a minimum deployment target of iOS 15?

Comment: it is better to add button for restore because they rejected mostly if you don't have restore button

Comment: But is it mandatory? Will it get rejected every time, or is it technically "reviewer-error" if it's rejected because of this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is yes for now.
Because Apple still says on their documentation to keep restore mechanism .
recently I worked on a project with StoreKit 2 and its required still to keep restore option.

from review guide documentation:

> you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable
> in-app purchases.

so I will recommend to keep it before sending review.

Comment: Already handling users with Original transaction id and Webhook. Then why restore button is necessary?

Comment: donno but Apple mentioned that on Their guideline for storekit 2

Comment: but maybe apple changes the policy now.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good question. The issue with restore purchases is that it is an app store guidelines requirement [3.1.1](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#payments)

> Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via in-app purchase may not expire, and you should make sure you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases.

Apple is known for its strict guidelines and application that will not offer a restore mechanism is likely to get rejected.

StoreKit2 like you mentioned aims to improve the user experience and reduce the friction of manual restoration using a button or such mechanism. But as far as I know it is still required.

Potentially if you can promise using StoreKit that the purchases will be available using some smart mechanism that I cannot think of, it might pass the review team.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I figured. Your logic makes sense to me.

Comment: With StoreKit 2 transition I couldn't restore IAP without at least once calling `AppStore.sync()`.